$T$ is a compact operator on a Banach space $X$, is $R(\lambda I-T)$ closed?
$T$ is a compact operator on a Banach space $X$, $0\ne \lambda\in\mathbb C$, is $R(\lambda I-T)$ closed in $X$?
Here $R(\lambda I-T)$ denotes the range of $\lambda I-T$.
Moreover, is $R((\lambda I-T)^n)$ closed in $X$?
I cannot think of a method to prove it or find a counterexample. I only find a similar question which is in Hilbert space.
Could you please give some hints? Many thanks in advance!

When $T$ is compact and $\lambda \neq 0$, the operator $\lambda I-T$ is Fredholm and thus has closed range (see for example Theorem 3.7.21 in applied functional analysis: An introduction)
